# xml parse error attribute name redefined

Tags: c

In my portscanner program, i wish to successfully write the output of the port number, scanned by and the service name.
so for each port number, scannedby and service name, i invoke the parseall routine below.

```
void parseall(int pid, char *scannedby, char *service){  // routine to add port, scannedby and service to xmlfile

  xmlDocPtr doc;  // pointer to parse xml Document

  xmlNodePtr cur = NULL;// node pointer. It interacts with individual node

  xmlAttrPtr attr; char portid[10];

  sprintf (portid,"%d",pid);  // converted int to string

  doc = xmlParseFile(xmlFileName); //parse filename

  cur = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);   // get rootnode

  addnewportinfotag(cur,doc);  // this routine adds new portid, scannedby and servicename tags to the xmlfile created

  cur = cur->xmlChildrenNode;  //get pointer

  parseport(doc, cur, portid);  // routine to add port to xmlfile

while(cur!=NULL){

if ((!xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *)"ports"))){

parsehost(doc, cur, scannedby);  // routine to add scanned by to xmlfile

parseservice(doc, cur, service); //routine to add servicename to xmlfile
}

cur = cur->next;

}

xmlSaveFormatFile (xmlFileName, doc, 1);

return;

xmlFreeDoc(doc);

}
```

the code compiles successfully but when i scan for more than one port, it gives an "xml parse error attribute name 
redefined" as below:

```
     [ Port  ] [ Scanned by] [ Status ] [Service]
     79/tcp     osus          Open      finger
     80/tcp       bt          Open        www
    111/tcp     osus          Open      sunrpc

xmloutput.xml:5: parser error : Attribute portid redefined
<ports protocol="tcp" portid="79" portid="80"><state state="open" reason="vanill
                                             ^
xmloutput.xml:5: parser error : Attribute scannedby redefined
e state="open" reason="vanilla-scan"/><scannedby scannedby="osus" scannedby="bt"
                                                                               ^
xmloutput.xml:5: parser error : Attribute name redefined
"/><scannedby scannedby="osus" scannedby="bt"/><service name="finger" name="www"
                                                                               ^
Segmentation fault
```

for a single port it works well giving:

```
<ports protocol="tcp" portid="22"><state state="open" reason="vanilla-scan"/><scannedby scannedby="bt"/><service name="ftp"/></ports></DPScanner>
```

Answer (score 8):

You're producing invalid XML. You can't have two attributes with the same name on the same tag.

See the spec, in the [Start-Tags, End-Tags, and Empty-Element Tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-attr):

> **Well-formedness constraint: Unique Att Spec**
>
> An attribute name must not appear more than once in the same start-tag or empty-element tag.

Comment: hi Mat, thanks for your quick response. the problem is somewhere in the function rather than creating new tags and filling the port info, it just appends the next port information to the next one. pls any help will be appreciated

Comment: That's invalid. You can't have to `port="..."` attributes on the same `ports` tag. You need to change the structure of your XML file so that port numbers are child elements, not attributes.